# I get an error every time I build i Next.js

Tags: javascript, next.js

I am using Next.js to create my own blog.

There are a lot of tag pages and category pages, and the build count is 3208 pages, which is quite a large number.

If there are too many, will Next give me an error when building?

further, It is not the same page every time, but different pages, etc.

For example, the error page is different for each build as follows.

The first time

```
Error occurred prerendering page "/entry/tags/hoge". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
Error: Request failed with status code 500
    at createError (/Users/next/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
    at settle (/Users/next/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)
    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/Users/next/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:293:11)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:402:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1343:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
```

The second time.

```
Error occurred prerendering page "/entry/tags/foo". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
Error: Request failed with status code 500
    at createError (/Users/next/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
    at settle (/Users/next/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)
    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/Users/next/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:293:11)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:402:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1343:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
```

If anyone can tell me what is causing this, I would appreciate your help.

Thank you.

---

### Additional Information at 2021.12.27

Here is the source code.
If you need any other information, please ask me anything.

Thank you.

##### /lib/posts.js

```
export const getPostsByTag = async ({tag, postsPerPage = 10, pageNum = ""} = {}) => {

  const params = {
    "tag"           : tag,
    "posts_per_page": postsPerPage,
    "page_num"      : pageNum,
  }

  let res = await axios.post(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_RESTAPI_URL}/custom/search_posts_by_tag`, params);
  return res.data;
}


// get all tags
export const getTags = async (count = "") => {

  const params = {
    "count": count,
  }

  const res = await axios.post(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_RESTAPI_URL}/custom/tags`, params);
  return res.data;
}
```

##### /pages/entry/tags/[tag].js

```
// lib
import {getPostsByTag, getTags} from "../../../lib/posts";

// components
import Layout from "../../../components/Layout";
import Post from "../../../components/Post";
import Pagination from "../../../components/Pagination";
import Seo from "../../../components/Seo";
import {useRouter} from "next/router";
import Loading from "../../../components/Loading";


export default function PaginationPerPage({posts, postsCount, archiveType, tagName, slug, currentPageNum}) {

  const router = useRouter();

  if (router.isFallback || !posts) {
    return <Loading/>
  }

  return (
    <>

      {/*---------------------   SEO   ---------------------*/}
      <Seo title="Tag List" description="this page is tag list."/>

      {/*---------------------   main   ---------------------*/}
      <Layout slug="archive">

        <h1>{tagName}</h1>

        <div className="posts">
          {posts && posts.map((post) => <Post key={post.id} post={post}/>)}
        </div>

        <Pagination
          postsCount={postsCount}
          archiveType={archiveType}
          slug={slug}
          currentPageNum={currentPageNum}
        />

      </Layout>

    </>
  )
}

export const getStaticPaths = async () => {

  let paths = [];

  /* -------  Prod  ------- */
  if (process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DEV === undefined) {

    // get all tags
    const fetchedTags = await getTags();

    paths = fetchedTags.tags.map(tag => {
      return {
        params: {
          tag: tag.slug,
        }
      }
    })
  }

  /* -------  Dev  ------- */
  if (process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DEV !== undefined) {
    paths = []
  }

  return {
    paths,
    fallback: true
  };
}


export async function getStaticProps({params}) {

  /* -------  get params from url  ------- */
  const slug = params.tag;
  const currentPageNum = 1;
  const archiveType = "tags";

  /* -------  posts per page  ------- */
  const fetchedPosts = await getPostsByTag({
    "tag": slug, "pageNum": 1
  });

  const tagName = fetchedPosts.name;
  const posts = fetchedPosts.posts;
  const postsCount = fetchedPosts.count;

  return {
    props     : {posts, postsCount, archiveType, tagName, slug, currentPageNum},
    revalidate: 3,
  };
}
```

Comment: We can't tell without looking at some relevant code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you also share the code for `getTags` and `getPostsByTag` functions? I'm assuming that's where `axios` is used, and where the error comes from.

Comment: @juliomalves

Thanks for the comment.

Of course it's okay. I made an addendum at the end of the question.

>I'm assuming that's where axios is used, and where the error comes from. 

I see...  I hadn't noticed that at all.
If there are any flaws, I would appreciate it if you could point them out.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).